# Black screen after i ran command

Tags: find, kali-linux, rm, data-recovery

I wanted to completely remove `pcsxr` and i type `-find / *pcsxr* -delete` and now my screen gone completely black. I don't know what to do and what i did wrong. I reboot now and I'm in boot menu and i think i deleted entire HDD. I had very important folder on desktop and i don't think i can do anything now.

Comment: Yes you told find to prune the entire root folder. Nothing is stopping you from using Testdisk or extundelete though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a Linux live CD, boot it, mount the HDD, and look around. You may have deleted enough files to render the system unbootable, but that doesn't mean you deleted everything.

Either way, don't kill yourself. No mistake is that bad. And from now own, make backups :)